# Typoscript: how do I add a parameter to all links in the RTE?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typolink

I want to add a parameter to **all** links entered in the RTE by the user.

My initial idea was to do this:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link {
    typolink.parameter.append = TEXT
    typolink.parameter.append.value = ?flavor=lemon
}
```

So for example:

```
http://domain.com/mypage.php
```

becomes

```
http://domain.com/mypage.php?flavor=lemon
```

which sounds great -- as long as the link does not **already** have a query string!
In that case, I obviously end up with two question marks in the URL

So for example:

```
http://domain.com/prefs.php?id=1234&unit=moon&qty=300
```

becomes

```
http://domain.com/prefs.php?id=1234&unit=moon&qty=300?flavor=lemon
```

Is there any way to add my parameter with the correct syntax, depending on whether the URL already has a query string or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, here's a solution that worked for me using the `replacement` function of Typoscript. Hope this helps.

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link {

    # Start by "replacing" the whole URL by itself + our string
    # For example: http://domain.com/?id=100    becomes http://domain.com/?id=100?flavor=lemon
    # For example: http://domain.com/index.html becomes http://domain.com/index.html?flavor=lemon

    typolink.parameter.stdWrap.replacement.10 {

        #this matches the whole URL
        search = #^(.*)$#i

        # this replaces it with itself (${1}) + our string
        replace =${1}?flavor=lemon

        # in this case we want to use regular expressions
        useRegExp = 1
    }

    # After the first replacement is done, we simply replace
    # the first '?' by '?' and all others by '&'
    # the use of Option Split allow this
    typolink.parameter.stdWrap.replacement.20 {
        search = ?
        replace = ? || & || &
        useOptionSplitReplace = 1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That would be the solution:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link {
    typolink.additionalParams = &flavor=lemon
}
```

Note that it has to start with an &, typo3 then generates a valid link. The parameter in the link also will be parsed with realURL if configured accordingly.

Edit: The above solution only works for internal links as described in the documentation https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink/Index.html

The only solution that works for all links that I see is to use a `userFunc`

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link {
    typolink.userFunc = user_addAdditionalParams
}
```

Then you need to create a php script and include in your TS with:

```
includeLibs.rteScript = path/to/yourScript.php
```

Keep in mind that includeLibs is outdated, so if you are using TYPO3 8.x (and probably 7.3+) you will need to create a custom extension with just a few files

```
<?php

function user_addAdditionalParams($finalTagParts) {
    // modify the url in $finalTagParts['url']
    // $finalTagParts['TYPE'] is an indication of link-kind: mailto, url, file, page, you can use it to check if you need to append the new params
    switch ($finalTagParts['TYPE']) {
        case 'url':
        case 'file':
            $parts = explode('#', $finalTagParts['url']);
            $finalTagParts['url'] = $parts[0] 
                . (strpos($parts[0], '?') === false ? '?' : '&') 
                . 'newParam=test&newParam=test2'
                . ($parts[1] ? '#' . $parts[1] : '');
        break;
    }
    return '<a href="' . $finalTagParts['url'] . '"' .
           $finalTagParts['targetParams'] .
           $finalTagParts['aTagParams'] . '>'
}
```

PS: i have not tested the actual php code, so it can have some errors. If you have troubles, try debugging the `$finalTagParts` variable

Comment: Sorry, this does not seem to work. It does not change anything in the links entered in the RTE. For example, **http://domain.com/blah** stays exactly the same, and **http://domain.com/blah?id=200** also stays exactly the same. My parameter never gets added. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: The solution with additionalParams only works for internal links, so I have added a more detailed comment on how to deal with external ones. I am positive that it can be archived with TypoScript only, but it would take a lot more time that the use of a `userFunc `

Comment: Thanks for your effort in answering my question. I'm a bit baffled that Typoscript does not offer a clean and simple way to test a string for a character and act accordingly, Oh well... thanks again for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Test whether the "?" character is already in the URL and append either "?" or "&", then append your key-value pair. There's a [CASE object available in the TypoScript Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/6.2/ContentObjects/Case/), with an example you can modify for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Unfortunately, I don't understand how to achieve this because I don't know how to test for "typolink contains character X". All the examples I've seen seem to use an exact string match. If you could provide a code example, that would be awesome. Thanks!